# Solr HTTP error: OK (400)?

Tags: search, solr

I have installed Solr search and configured in magento admin, Test Connection successfully. After that I tried to Reindex. I am getting error while reindex catalog search via SSH.

```
"Catalog Search indexer process unknown error:
Solr HTTP error: OK (400)
{"responseHeader":{"status":400,"QTime":0},"error":{"msg":"undefined field store_id","code":400}}"
```

If I change change search engine to solr to other(MySQL), I am able to reindex catalog search. But I can't reindex catalog search while using solr search engine.

Anyone knows solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an issue on Solr end but catalog search configuration on magento end.

The error means magento is trying to reindex "store_id" field but it couldn't find "store_id" on schema.xml file. In other words, you should explicitly define Solr Server Path on Magento-admin-Stores->Configuration->Catalog->Catalog->Catalog Search. Instead of defining Solr server path as just "solr" , you should define as "solr/magento2" where magento2 is your solr collection defined on solr. This happens when you have multiple collections as it takes default collection when not defined explicitly.

And, collection name isn't checked when connection is tested. A connection test is merely connecting to solr server with IP and port provided. So, successful connection doesn't necessarily guarantee that search works.